# Random images appearing in my home directory... Where are they coming from?

Tags: home-directory, tv

Here's an odd problem I've had for a while. Every so often, I find that I have several jpeg images sitting in my home directory that I didn't put there. I'm fairly sure this isn't a security breach but rather, there's something writing these files in there that I've forgotten about.

Here's what I'm looking at today:

```
oli@bert:~$ ls -l *.jpg
-rw------- 1 oli oli  8061 2010-11-19 18:30 An-alien-from-Mars-Attack-002.jpg
-rw------- 1 oli oli 24362 2010-11-19 18:30 An-alien-from-Mars-Attack-006.jpg
-rw------- 1 oli oli  8147 2010-11-05 18:08 Avatar-Film---2009-002.jpg
-rw------- 1 oli oli 35602 2010-11-05 18:08 Avatar-Film---2009-006.jpg
-rw------- 1 oli oli  6058 2010-12-03 18:42 Britney-Spears-victim-of--002.jpg
-rw------- 1 oli oli 28330 2010-12-03 18:42 Britney-Spears-victim-of--006.jpg
-rw------- 1 oli oli  8135 2010-11-12 19:19 charlie-brooker-twitter-p-002.jpg
-rw------- 1 oli oli 22115 2010-11-12 19:19 charlie-brooker-twitter-p-006.jpg
-rw------- 1 oli oli  8059 2010-10-29 18:47 Leonardo-DiCaprio-002.jpg
-rw------- 1 oli oli 29988 2010-10-29 18:47 Leonardo-DiCaprio-006.jpg
-rw------- 1 oli oli  8064 2010-10-22 16:41 Spot-the-difference-.-.-.-002.jpg
-rw------- 1 oli oli 29188 2010-10-22 16:41 Spot-the-difference-.-.-.-006.jpg
```

They all seem like they're TV or film related... But I honestly don't have a clue what could be writing them. They don't bother me enough to go on a full-scale witch hunt but if anybody knows of something that writes images in the home directory like this, please let me know.

Comment: What software do you use to watch TV? You may be accidentally pressing the snapshot button.

Comment: They seem to come from http://www.guardian.co.uk - maybe a browser plugin gone haywire?

Comment: You can use http://www.tineye.com/ to try identify where they came from originally

Comment: @badp I don't watch TV on this computer, although I have in the past. I still have `gnome-dvb-client`, `gnome-dvb-daemon` and `totem-plugins-dvb-daemon` installed although I'm sure I've been getting these files longer than I've ever had those installed. Edit: I've just removed them

Comment: @htorque I do visit the Guardian website every once in a while. I'll visit it now in a couple of browsers and see if any new files get saved.

Comment: Your files have specific time-stamp detail. Can't you recall what was going on at these times with your machine (assuming you are the only one using it). There has to be a single app using your HOME as its target point.

Comment: @nik That's a good observation but it's also an odd thing. In the evening, I tend to not use the computer... Especially between 5pm and 7pm, I'll be away from it, watching telly, making dinner, etc.

Comment: It's also interesting that the files are only saved on Fridays. The mask is also not typical, I hear that FF4.0 does this when saving files. I'd also suggest looking at the images' metadata, there can be some more info.

Comment: Hey Oli, still having this befuddling issue?

Comment: @jrg - desktop has been in headless/X-less mode for a month and has only just come back online but yes, it's still happening. Nothing from when it was in headless mode, suggesting it's something within my graphical session that's doing it.

Comment: @Oli OK, that's odder than odder than odd.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have a toddler, a cat or another creature that would trigger some "save" feature of a browser left running on the foreground?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try running fatrace (see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/105197/3037)) and when those images appear again, search for them in fatrace's log file. That hopefully will reveal the program that's acting up. :)

Answer (score 3):

No amount of investigation actually solved this but I did stop using Liferea and started using Lightread for reading my RSS feeds. The images stopped popping up.

Comment: I guess that solves the mystery.

Comment: I would say Liferea uses your home as image cache for stuff.

Comment: That was my assumption but it wasn't consistent. It was as if only *some* of one feed's images were being fetched into the wrong place (as if there were an unescaped relative path like `../../../img.jpg`) but I never got around to reporting it because I never had the proof.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible at the moment. I had a look into inotify and back in 2008 a developer wanted to put the PID of the process that created the file event into the cookie information. This would have solved it as you could have created a python program to grab the name of the process with that PID... in fact I created just a script to test the idea.

But the patch was thrown out for security reasons and a second patch may or may not have been submitted which needs some kind of options flag which isn't in pyinofity anyway.

So then I looked at lsof, it's a one shot deal so it's likely to miss the perp most of the time, but you might get lucky with or with the additional `-r 1` to repeat every 1 second.

```
lsof +d ~/
```

At any rate this is a bit of a missing functionality in the workings of Linux and should probably be fixed. Report a bug to the Linux kernel and/or inotify explaining that a command line tool to watch for which processes are writing files would be most welcome.