# Monitor which process changed the file

Tags: 11.10, filesystem, monitoring

I want to know which process changed files in some directory.

I had a look at inotify-tools, but it doesn't show the pid. I also look at fileschanged utility, but in my case it doesn't show anything at all, even that change happened.

Is there solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [fatrace](http://www.piware.de/2012/02/fatrace-report-system-wide-file-access-events/) written by [Martin Pitt](https://launchpad.net/~pitti).

It will monitor all system-wide reads/writes/opens/closes alongside the PIDs and the names of their processes.

1. Get it:

   ```
   bzr branch lp:fatrace
   ```
2. Build it:

   ```
   cd fatrace
   make
   ```
3. Run it:

   ```
   sudo ./fatrace -t | grep "/path/to/your/file"
   ```

Comment: great tool, thanks! it would be better if I could make inotify tell process id, but if it's not possible, then I will use fatrace

Comment: What if you want to run it as a daemon?  I tried `sudo fatrace/fatrace -t | grep "/home/eric/test.txt" >> ./monitor.txt &` but nothing gets inserted into monitor.txt